# Put 2 divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with this:
http://jsfiddle.net/u3c6g5jx/

The thing I want to do, is have the title over the boxes and have the two divs next to each other.

Thank you

Here is the code:

***HTML:***

```
    <div>
    <div id="halftitle" style="float:left;">title</div>
    <div id="halfbloc" style="float:left;"> <a href="<?php echo $host ?>george.php">link1</a>
        </br>username, 1 hour ago</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="halftitle" style="float:left;">title</div>
    <div id="halfbloc" style="float:left;"> <a href="<?php echo $host ?>george.php">link1</a>
        </br>username, 1 hour ago</div>
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
    #halftitle {
    background-image:linear-gradient(to top, #0e75ba, #021c55);
    padding: 2px 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width:40%;
}
#halfbloc {
    background-color: #f7fafb;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    width:40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `float:left` of the #halfblock and add `clear:both`;

```css
#halftitle {
    background-image:linear-gradient(to top, #0e75ba, #021c55);
    padding: 2px 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width:100%;
}
#halfbloc {
    background-color: #f7fafb;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    width:100%;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:40%; display:inline-block; margin:1%;">
    <div id="halftitle" style="float:left;">title</div>
    <div id="halfbloc"> <a href="<?php echo $host ?>george.php">link1</a>
        </br>username, 1 hour ago</div>
</div>
<div style="width:40%; display:inline-block; margin:1%;">
    <div id="halftitle" style="float:left;">title</div>
    <div id="halfbloc"> <a href="<?php echo $host ?>george.php">link1</a>
        </br>username, 1 hour ago</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome ;). Notice that in the parent div of each box, I have set the width of 40% and display:inline-block, and in the #halfblock a width of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the surrounding divs are too wide. Try setting the width of the divs to the size you want then setting the inner divs' width to 100%.

```css
#halftitle {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #0e75ba, #021c55);
  padding: 2px 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
#halfbloc {
  background-color: #f7fafb;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="halftitle" style="float:left;">title</div>
  <div id="halfbloc" style="float:left;"> <a href="<?php echo $host ?>george.php">link1</a>
    <br>username, 1 hour ago</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="halftitle" style="float:left;">title</div>
  <div id="halfbloc" style="float:left;"> <a href="<?php echo $host ?>george.php">link1</a>
    <br>username, 1 hour ago</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your two containing `div`s `class="container"` and then write this rule:

```
.container {
    float: left; /* or display: inline-block; if you prefer */
    width: 49%;
}
```

[See it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3c6g5jx/2/).

Note that to make it look right, I fixed the `padding`, `width`, and `margin`s of the other `div`s. Since width is in percent, you need horizontal `margin`s and `padding` to also be in percent, and it always needs to add up to 100%, so I've done that for you in the JSFiddle.